# Why sound does not work when I boot connected to external LG monitor? Fedora 38

Tags: fedora, audio, multi-monitor

When I boot with my external LG (HDMI) monitor sound does not work (it shows up as No output or Dummy sound) on my Dell, Fedora 38.

If I boot without it connected and then connect it it works. I use a USB hub (well, not just USB, HDMI and VGA too) that goes into the Dell USB-C port.

I think it started recently.

I did some research but found nothing specific. I'm no expert though.

Any suggestions? Thanks anyway.

(PS I dual-boot Fedora 38 and Windows 11, if it makes any difference.)

Comment: I would start by disabling Fast Boot in UEFI ("BIOS").

Comment: @ChanganAuto I will google that and then try that. Thank you!